# Using ShellTileSchedule in WP8 with Wide Tiles

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to use ShellTileSchedule in Windows Phone 8 to update wide tiles?

Windows 8 has TileUpdateManager with StartPeriodicUpdate method which is perfect for what I want to do but I can't find equivalent in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: This should do it.  I don't have a code sample, but give me a bit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769548(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: "The background image for the front of the Tile is the only property that you can update using ShellTileSchedule." ~ from the link above

Comment: Using a ShellTileSchedule to update the Medium Background and a Scheduled task to update the rest of the tile may be as close as you can get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ***is*** possible to use `ShellTileSchedule` to update the wide background see http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Generating_Live_tiles_for_Windows_Phone_from_Live_Data

Answer (score 0):

No, the `ShellTileSchedule` only supports one resolution remote image. Instead you should use a `PeriodicTask` background agent and update the tile yourself (using C#)